# Parsing large CSV in Perl

Tags: memory-management, xml, csv, perl, xpath

I am getting `Out of Memory` errors when I try to parse through a large CSV file (2.5Gb). My computer has 32Gb of Memory but Perl uses all of it up. The CSV has 2 columns.  The first is the time in epoch and the second is a 10000+ line XML file as a single-line. There are around 13k rows. I then use XML::XPath to retrieve the customer name and save the XML to `[customername]-[time].xml`. If there is an error, it is because the XML is invalid and I skip it.

Is there any way to make my code run more efficiently and look better?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;
use File::Slurp;

my $file = '../FILENAME.csv';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
my $count = 0;
$| = 1;

while( my $line = <$info>)  {
    next if ++$count == 1; #Ignore headers
    my ($time, $report) = ($line =~ /(\d+),(.*)$/); # time, XML file
    eval {
        my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $report);
        our $ext = $xp->getNodeText('/report/customer') . "-" . $time . ".xml";
        write_file($ext, $report);
    };
    if ( $@ ) {printf "ERROR ";}
    else {printf "$count ";}
}

close $info;
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Parse::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CSV) for the CSV loading? From the POD: "A number of other modules have attempted to put usability wrappers around [Text::CSV_XS], but they have all focused on parsing the entire file into memory at once. This method is fine unless your CSV files start to get large. [...] Parse::CSV fills this functionality gap."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suspicious of this line here:

> ```
> my ($time, $report) = ($line =~ /(\d+),(.*)$/); # time, XML file
> ```

That line needs to scan and group the entire XML doc, but my instinct is that [a 2-limited split (see note on LIMIT)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) would be more efficient:

```
my ($time, $report) = split /,/, $line, 2;
```

Apart from that, really, everything looks sane, and far better than a typical perl hack. I am impressed.

About perl using all your memory... are you sure? perl may just be struggling to allocate more than it is allowed. Do you have a ulimit condition that is constraining memory allocation? Are there problems with heavily fragmented memory? (You're not running 32-bit, are you... just checking?)

As it happens, for a task like this, you may find that everything is better with a language other than perl. Not to dismiss perl as incapable, but with the XPath expressions and other items your code looks surprisingly complicated. 2.5gig files are way beyond the normal I would consider for perl performance.

Comment: Well the XML report MAY contain commas. But the files are always in the format `1234567890,<XML Report>` so I guess i just want the epoch time to be $time and everything else to be $report.

Comment: @Bijan - Note where I said the 2-limit split... if the XML contains commas that's fine. See the doc: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html (Look for the LIMIT paragraph)

Comment: I should have taken a screenshot but Perl was using 31GB of my memory.  Windows was creating an extremely large paging file (90Gb) and i was running out of room on my SSD so I limited the paging file to 40Gb.
Would my code run much more efficiently if I got rid of the XPath to get customer name? I can always name file to the epoch time, it's not a big deal to have customer name

Comment: @Bijan - it is very hard to imagine why your code is exploding in memory like that. It makes no sense, and is going in to the realm of perl bugs, not program bugs. From a review perspective, though, your code looks fine. I would consider slurping the entire input file, and manually identifying line-breaks. That would be my next course of action.

Comment: Is running XPath thousdands of times taxing on memory?

Comment: @Bijan - let's take this to [the 2nd monitor chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: The OP's code stores each XML document 3 times in memory (`$line`, `$report`, and `$xp`), including once in an `XML::XPath` object, which will certainly use more memory than a regular scalar variable.